# MVC HttpGet Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC noob here and cannot find a simple enough explanation from this.

I just started working on a fairly large app built with MVC.

In the controller I'm using, most of the `ActionResults` have the `[HttpGet]` attribute appended to them.  So I'm building off that code, and I built two `ActionResults` myself but left the `[HttpGet]` attributes off.

These make calls out to the database layer and then return results to the view.  They work fine.  When I noticed they didn't have `[HttpGet]` on them, I added them and then the calls stopped working. I can't figure out why, or the rhyme and reason for when they have to be there.

Here's a call I'm making from the view:

```
function getExcelExport() {
var activePane = $('div.tab-pane.active');

var agencyCompany = $(activePane).find('#Agency_AgencyId').val();
if (!$(activePane).find('#form0').valid()) { return false; }
var month = $(activePane).find('#CommissionMonth').val();
var year = $(activePane).find('#CommissionYear').val();

window.location = 'AgencyManagement/GetCommissionsExcel?agencyID=' + agencyCompany + '&month=' + month + '&year=' + year;
};
```

and here's the action in the controller:

```
        public ActionResult GetCommissionsExcel(string agencyid, string month, string year)
    {
        try
        {
            var as400rep = new iSeriesRepository(new iSeriesContext());
            var results = as400rep.GetCommissionExcel(agencyid, month, year);

            string xml = String.Empty;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(results.GetType());

            using (System.IO.MemoryStream xmlStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, results);
                xmlStream.Position = 0;
                xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
                xml = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
            }

            var fName = string.Format("CommissionsExcelExport-{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
            fName = fName + ".xls";

            byte[] fileContents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

            return File(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fName);
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Is there a simple explanation for this?

Comment: How are you making the call to the action? If it's Ajax are you specifying the type as GET or POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that when you added `[HttpGet]` and the calls 'stopped' working is because you would be calling the method using a different HTTP verb e.g. `POST`.

Applying a Http verb attribute on a method means, [to restrict an action method so that the method handles only HTTP GET requests.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpgetattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

The reason why it all worked when you did not use a http verb attribute is because that action method is then available via all Http verbs.

Mark that Action Method with `[HttpPost]` and it will work.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(int id)
{
}
```

You are able to have the same Method name for a `GET` and a `POST`, but the method requires a different signature (overloading).

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Action() { }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(int id) { }
```

This is usually used in a PRG pattern (POST, Redirect, GET). You can read further about this [here](https://www.jamietech.com/2015/10/19/mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/)

Comment: Okay, tried it and that worked.  So the reason it works without the attributes is because there's only one action with that name right?  If there were two, a GET action and a POST action, I'd have to specify, which makes sense.

Comment: I'll add an example with a GET and  a POST, If you do not put a http verb attribute then that method is accessible via all verbs, POST,GET,PUT etc.

Comment: Terrific explanation Jamie, sorry it had to get to the ELI5 level :), thank you!

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild That's fine! Everyone has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

`[HttpGet]` marks the Action as application only for GET requests -

Consider the following:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething() { }
```

if you were to GET to /DoSomething OR POST /DoSomething - the action would be invoked.

Specifying:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DoSomething() { }
```

ensures this is only going to be called if the request was a GET

Comment: Okay, so in one case I'm getting a list of months.  The call comes from the view as such:

    window.location = 'Agency/GetCommissions?agencyID=' + agencyCompany + '&month=' + month + '&year=' + year;

That call goes out to the data layer, which calls the database, brings back the list, and populates the view.  So it's a get correct?  If I put the [HttpGet] attribute on the action, it won't display.  Can you explain why?

and thanks for your response.

Comment: can you edit your question ans show more of your code? particularly the js calling off to your mvc controllers